# javascript assign variable value to checkbox status in html page

Tags: javascript, html, variables, checkbox

I am very new to javascript, and this seems like a very simple problem but despite many similar posts none seem to point to a solution for me.

I have the following code in a script of an html page:

```
$.get( "data.php", { getlocks: 1}, function( data ) { //Pull checkbox status from database (so it isn't lost on a page refresh)
    wl = data.split(" ");
    document.getElementById("lock369").checked = 1;
    document.getElementById("lock399").checked = 0;
    document.getElementById("lock935").checked = wl[2];
    document.getElementById("test1").value = wl[0];
    document.getElementById("test2").value = wl[1];
    document.getElementById("test3").value = wl[2];
});
```

Where `"lock369"` and `"lock935"` are set to constants just for my sanity to ensure the page is loading properly. The problem is no matter how I setup `"lock935"` it comes out as checked even when `wl[2]` is zero. (I have text boxes `"test1"` - `"test3"` displaying the 3 elements of `wl` so I am sure they are getting the correct values from the database they're pulled from, via `data.php`).

Originally I had all three checkboxes set to their respective elements of `wl` and the same issue occurs for all of them so it's not something funny with only `"lock935"`. I have also tried assigning the values of `wl` to individual variables and setting `document.getElementById("lockXXX").checked` equal to those variables, this didn't solve the issue. I also tried putting `wl[X]` in paranthesis, quotes, single quotes, etc. and nothing made a difference.

As I mentioned I'm very new to js so if this is a simple negligence on my part just kindly yell at me for it and I'll correct my ways in the future :)

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to set them to numbers at all? It's a boolean. It should be true or false.

Comment: That's just how the database worked out - it was much simpler to just use 1/0. I can try to switch it but it would take a bit of time - do you think it would make a difference?

Comment: Oh wow that actually did fix it...derp okay thanks!

Comment: 0 and 1 can be used just fine, they get casted to boolean; the real problem is that your numbers are strings and not actual numbers. My answer explains how to cast them on use (without the need of a switch)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, please add that little bit to your answer and I'll select it as the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with using 0 and 1 as boolean, just make sure that if it is coming from your database in string form that you call *parseInt* on it or cast it to a *Number*.

Examples:

```
document.getElementById("lock935").checked = parseInt(wl[2], 10);
```

OR

```
document.getElementById("lock935").checked = Number(wl[2]);
```

*parseInt* will return `NaN` in the case of an empty string and using `Number()` will return `0`. Both `NaN` and `0` will result in an unchecked box so it's really up to you.

*Edit: fixed some verbiage in explanation and a typo in the code.*

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
document.getElementById("lock935").checked = wl[2]=="1"?true:false;
```

Comment: I just tried something less elegant but similar and it worked - just tried yours and of course it works too, Thanks!

Comment: A simplier form will be: document.getElementById("lock935").checked = (wl[2]=="1")